# Combo Chart not selecting data correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I can't figure out why the combo chart is not treating the second LA as the start of the line graph series.  It knows what to do with MS and TX, but is making LA another bar instead of a line.  Thoughts?  Thanks in advance.  :0

[combo chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnuQL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your chart by right-clicking on it and clicking **Change Chart Type** item. On the new opened window you can set which series should be which type. For example;

[image: Change Chart Type Window]